# Blazor server Javascript function not working when page changes

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

Blazor server application.I have a razor component which will search Car VRN. User will be able to draw on the car diagram using canvas. On the first search, drawing is working. But if i search second car number and try to draw on the canvas its not working. Something wrong with javascript loading?

```
<MudCard>
    <MudCardContent>
        <MudGrid>
            <MudItem xs="6" sm="6" md="6" lg="6">
                <MudTextField @bind-Value="searchVRN" Label="VRN" Variant="Variant.Outlined"></MudTextField>
            </MudItem>
            <MudItem xs="6" sm="2" md="2" lg="2" Class="pt-5">
                <MudButton Variant="Variant.Outlined" Color="MudBlazor.Color.Primary" EndIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" OnClick="()=>loadVehicleData()">
                    Search
                </MudButton>
            </MudItem>
        </MudGrid>
    </MudCardContent>
</MudCard>
@if (_vehicleMasterV !=null)
{
    <_VehicleCheckIn _vehicleMasterV="@_vehicleMasterV"></_VehicleCheckIn>
}
```

code behind

```
partial class CheckIn : ComponentBase
    {
        private FVehicleMasterV _vehicleMasterV { get; set; }
        public string searchVRN { get; set; }
        
        private async void loadVehicleData()
        {
            var data = await _masterService.GetVehicleDetail("VRN", searchVRN);
            _vehicleMasterV = data.Data;
            await InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                StateHasChanged();
            });
        }
       
    }
```

It will load below razor component

```
@if (_vehicleMasterV != null && IsAllLoaded)
{
    <EditForm Model="_checkInDTO" OnValidSubmit="CheckInEvent">
        <_VehicleBasicDetail _vehicleMasterV="_vehicleMasterV"></_VehicleBasicDetail>
        <MudDivider style="border-color:dodgerblue" />
        <MudCard Elevation="6">
            <MudCardContent>
                <MudGrid>
                    <MudItem xs="12" sm="4" md="4" lg="4" Class="pa-1">
                        <MudTextField Label="Milage" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Required="true"
                        @bind-Value="_checkInDTO.Milage" For="@(() => _checkInDTO.Milage)" />
                    </MudItem>
                    
                    <MudItem xs="12" sm="12" md="12" lg="12" Class="pa-1">
                        <MudTextField Label="CheckIn Comments" Variant="Variant.Outlined" @bind-Value="_checkInDTO.CheckinComments" For="@(() => _checkInDTO.CheckinComments)" Lines="3" />
                    </MudItem>
                </MudGrid>
            </MudCardContent>
        </MudCard>

        <MudCard Elevation="6">
            <MudCardContent>
                <MudGrid>
                    @if (_vehicleMasterV == null || _vehicleMasterV.VehicleTypeCode != 4)
                    {
                        <MudItem xs="12" sm="7" md="7" lg="7" Class="pa-0">
                           <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="515" height="360" style="background-image:url(images/MC515.jpg);position:relative"></canvas>
                        </MudItem>
                    }
                 
                </MudGrid>
            </MudCardContent>
        </MudCard>
    </EditForm>
 
}
```

code behind to load javascript

```
 protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            jsModule = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/CheckOut.js");
        }
    }
```

This is my javascript file

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
if (canvas == null) {
    alert('Its null');
    //return;
}
else {
    alert(document.getElementById('canvas'));
    var clearBtn = document.getElementById("clear");
    var colorBtn = document.getElementById("color");
    var strokeInput = document.getElementById("stroke");
    var intrumentSelect = document.getElementById("intrument");

    var BB = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var offsetX = BB.left;
    var offsetY = BB.top;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var config_color = colorBtn.value;
    var config_stroke_width = strokeInput.value;
    var config_instrument = drawLine;
    //canvas.onwheel = function (event) {
    //    event.preventDefault();
    //};

    //canvas.onmousewheel = function (event) {
    //    event.preventDefault();
    //};

    clearBtn.addEventListener("click", clearCanvas);
    colorBtn.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
        config_color = e.target.value;
    });

    strokeInput.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
        config_stroke_width = e.target.value;
    });

    intrumentSelect.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
        var value = e.target.value;

        if (value == LINE_INSTRUMENT) {
            config_instrument = drawLine;
        } else if (value == RECTANGLE_INSTRUMENT) {
            config_instrument = drawRect;
        }
    });
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", prepareToDrawing);
    function prepareToDrawing(target) {

        var x = target.layerX;
        var y = target.layerY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);

        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", config_instrument);

        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
            canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", config_instrument);
        });
        ///
        //canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", config_instrument);

        //canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function () {
        //    canvas.removeEventListener("touchmove", config_instrument);
        //});

    }

    function drawLine(target) {

        var x = target.layerX;
        var y = target.layerY;

        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.lineWidth = config_stroke_width;
        ctx.strokeStyle = config_color;
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function drawRect(target) {
        var x = target.layerX;
        var y = target.layerY;
        var w = 10;
        var h = 10;

        ctx.fillStyle = config_color;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    function animate(delay) {
        var w = Math.random() * 110;
        var h = Math.random() * 110;
        var x = Math.round(Math.random() * 10) * w;
        var y = Math.round(Math.random() * 10) * h;
        var color = getRandomHEX();

        drawRect(x, y, w, h, color);

        window.setTimeout(function () {
            animate(delay);
        }, delay);
    }

    function clearCanvas() {
        alert('clear');
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

    /******** HELPERS ********/

    function getRandomHEX() {
        return "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    }
    function GetDataUrl() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
        alert(dataUrl);
        console.log(dataUrl);
    }
    function drawDataURIOnCanvas(strDataURI, canvas) {
        var myCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = mycanvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image;
        img.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); // Or at whatever offset you like
        };
        img.src = strDataURI;
    }
    
}
```